# Python - REGEX issue with RE using function re.compile + search

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I'm using regex library 're' in Python (2.7) to validate a flight number.

I've had no issues with expected outputs using a really helpful online editor here: http://regexr.com/

My results on regexr.com are: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YC7ra.jpg

My code is:

```
import re
test1 = 'ba116'
###Referencelink: http://academe.co.uk/2014/01/validating-flight-codes/
p = re.compile('/^([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])[a-z]?[0-9]{1,4}[a-z]?$/g')
m = p.search(test1)  # p.match() to find from start of string only
if m:
print 'It works!: ', m.group()  # group(1...n) for capture groups
else:
print 'Did not work'
```

I'm unsure why I get the 'didn't work' output where regexr shows one match (as expected)

I made a much simpler regex lookup, and it *seemed* that the results were correct, so it seems either my regex string is invalid, or I'm using re.complile (or perhaps the if loop) incorrectly?

'ba116' is valid, and should match.

Comment: Is your code really indented like that?  It should be throwing a syntax error.

Comment: Remove the `/` you don't need them in python. Thats probably why its not working

Comment: Yes. As in: http://imgur.com/QqK3HsX - I don't get any errors; code executes and ends with 'Process finished with exit code 0'

Comment: Removed '/' resulting in: p = re.compile('^([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])[a-z]?[0-9]{1,4}[a-z]?$g') - but exact same result

Comment: remove the 'g' at the end too

Comment: ... So, in fact, your code is NOT indented the way it is shown in the text of the question.  Python is an [offside-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule) language; it is critical to preserve its indentation when providiing people with code samples.

Answer (score 1):

Python's `re.compile` is treating your leading `/` and trailing `/g` as part of the regular expression, not as delimiters and modifiers.  This produces a compiled RE that will never match anything, since you have `^` with stuff before it and `$` with stuff after it.

The first argument to `re.compile` should be a string containing *only* the stuff you would put inside the slashes in a language that had `/.../` regex notation.  The `g` modifier corresponds to calling the `findall` method on the compiled RE; in this case it appears to be unnecessary.  (Some of the other modifiers, e.g. `i`, `s`, `m`, correspond to values passed to the *second* argument to `re.compile`.)

So this is what your code should look like:

```
import re
test1 = 'ba116'
###Referencelink: http://academe.co.uk/2014/01/validating-flight-codes/
p = re.compile(r'^([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])[a-z]?[0-9]{1,4}[a-z]?$')
m = p.search(test1)  # p.match() to find from start of string only
if m:
    print 'It works!: ', m.group()  # group(1...n) for capture groups
else:
    print 'Did not work'
```

The `r` immediately before the open quote makes no difference for *this* regular expression, but if you needed to use backslashes in the RE it would save you from having to double all of them.